# Putting a fixed row containing Textfield in p:dataTable

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I want do the following scenario using DataTable:

- By default there should be only one row in datatable which will have
  a InputTextfield and a Button.
- Once user types Name and clicks on
  that button,Name should be add to Data table.
- This process will repeat many times.

**1**

[image]

**2**

[image]

**3**

[image]

Any ideas how to do this?
Had any one done this before?
Please give your suggestions.

EDIT: ***The Images above are altered in Photoshop, NOT the exact output of my Code.***

Comment: It looks pretty much straight forward.. What code hove you tried?

Comment: @fareed : Its Photoshoped.

Comment: I meant the logic is straight forward. Have you tried any codes that didn't work out for you?

Comment: And why would you want a Datatable if you want only one row, one inputtext, and one button? Isn't it easier to make it outside a datatable?

Comment: You can put the table title and input component in a two-rows-PanelGrid and place it into the header section of the dataTable, using `<f:facet name="header">`

Comment: Thanks @perissf. If still there any other methods then do share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As persissf said you can use header for input.

i have the sample code for your question .

```
@SessionScoped
@ManagedBean

public class DataBean implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    List<String> data;
    String name;

    public DataBean(){
        data=new ArrayList<String>();
    }
    /**
     * @return the data
     */
    public List<String> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    /**
     * @param data the data to set
     */
    public void setData(List<String> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    /**
     * @return the name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * @param name the name to set
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void update(){
        data.add(name);
    }


}
```

View:

```
<h:body>
    <h:form prependId="false">

    <p:dataTable value="#{dataBean.data}" var="data" id="datatable">

        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="UserNames:" />
                <h:inputText value="#{dataBean.name}" />
                <p:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{dataBean.update}"
                    update="@form,datatable">
                </p:commandButton>
            </f:facet>

            <h:outputText value="#{data}" />
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>

</h:form>
```

hope this will answer your question..